# How do I use config vars in React Native

Tags: git, react-native, github, expo

I am working on an open source React Native app with Expo. I have some sensitive details that shouldn't be committed to the repo (my Sentry and Amplitude API keys). I am aware I can keep them in `config.js` file and add it to my `.gitignore`, but I would like to keep my build (publish) process automated with CI (I don't want to publish from my local machine). How should I go about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
1 > Open GitLab repo of your project.
2 > Now Goto CICD setting and expand the `Variables` property
3 > add 'Input variable key' like `CONFIG_JS` and paste all your content of a config.js file as an 'Input variable value' 
4 > It is secure, So don't worry about security
```

After doing this step add below lines in your `.gitlab-ci.yml` file before `android-bundle` or `android-release` command in a script

```
 - mkdir /Config
 - "echo $CONFIG_JS > /Config/config.js" # replace CONFIG_JS with your variable name that you set in CICD settings
```

above command make a  `Config` directory at runtime and make a config.js file from variable value. 
all you need to do is just import config.js file from 'Config/config' file

and thats it :)